# Код работает только при активной панели разработчика в браузере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема, чувствую, пустяковая, но все же остается для меня проблемой. Код работает только при активной панели разработчика в браузере (проверял Яндекс.Браузер и Firefox), а также на телефоне.  При клике на `<div class="open_fall_menu"></div>` с активной панелью задач все работает, а при закрытой ни в какую не чувствует клик. Ниже привел "нерабочий" код. Учусь сей магии верстки с месяц в домашних условиях, поэтому, пожалуйста, разжуйте решение как можно подробнее без метания помидоров.

P.S. Проверить неработоспособность можно [тут](https://huzyagulover.github.io/Some-Repository/) (в конце страницы)

```js
document.querySelector('.open_fall_menu').addEventListener('click', function fallingMenu() {
  let fallMenu = this.nextElementSibling.classList;
  fallMenu.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
#css13 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
}

#css13 div {
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
}

#css13 .open_fall_menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 10px 7px 10px;
}

#css13 .open_fall_menu>.burger_line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #B200FF;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

#css13 .fall_menu {
  width: calc(100vw/5);
  height: calc(100vh/3);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #231d51;
}

#css13 .fall_menu {
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotateX(86deg);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s linear 0.4s, transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.275, 0.825, 0.115) 0s;
}

#css13 .fall_menu.active {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s linear 0s, transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="css13">
  <div class="open_fall_menu">
    <div class="burger_line"></div>
    <div class="burger_line"></div>
    <div class="burger_line"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="fall_menu"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так а что не работает-то?

Comment: @AlexSazonov, уточнил проблему в вопросе

Comment: Проблема в том что в свернутом состоянии вы элементом `.fall_menu `перекрываете саму кнопку. добавьте для `open_fall_menu` `cursor:pointer` и будете видеть срабатывает или нет. В представленном выше снипетте работает, вопрос что при открытом дебаге работает - не верен так как видимо вы используете закрепленный дебаг (что уменьшает окно) большинство используют инспектор в отдельном окне, и тогда никакого влияния на поиск ошибки не будет)

Comment: Простое решение  `visibility: hidden;` ,     `visibility: visible;`

Comment: Добавил рабочий фикс ниже. Не используйте инспектор в окне страницы, используйте в отдельном окне. Вы себя же запутали этим и пошли не в верном направлении в поисках ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас при некоторых разрешениях скрытый элемент перекрывает кнопку

> с активной панелью задач все работает, а при закрытой ни в какую не чувствует клик

Уточнение не верное, зависит от разрешение экрана при котором свернутый `.fall_menu` перекрывает кнопку. Если вы инспектор откроете в новом окне то влияние никакого на работу кнопки не будет

Простое решение добавить `visibility: hidden;` , `visibility: visible;`

```js
document.querySelector('.open_fall_menu').addEventListener('click', function fallingMenu() {
  let fallMenu = this.nextElementSibling.classList;
  fallMenu.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
#css13 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
}

#css13 div {
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
}

#css13 .open_fall_menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 10px 7px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}

#css13 .open_fall_menu>.burger_line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #B200FF;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

#css13 .fall_menu {
  width: calc(100vw/5);
  height: calc(100vh/3);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #231d51;
}

#css13 .fall_menu {
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotateX(86deg);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s linear 0.4s, transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.275, 0.825, 0.115) 0s;
visibility: hidden;
}

#css13 .fall_menu.active {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s linear 0s, transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) 0s;

visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="css13">
  <div class="open_fall_menu">
    <div class="burger_line"></div>
    <div class="burger_line"></div>
    <div class="burger_line"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="fall_menu"></div>
</div>
```